# How to check the value is not present in the array in where clause in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql

I want to select cid value from the table Customers which is not present in the array that is being populated at runtime

what I have done so far:

```
if (RANDOM() >= 0.05) then
    Customer[counter] := (select cid from aa_dev.Customer where cid not in (Customer[]) order by random() limit 1);
else
    Customer[counter] = null;
end if;
```

This is a chunk of code, here in the if condition I want to select cid from a table customer and dump that selected id to an array, I want the array populated with unique cids, so in where clause I want to check and select only that cid which has not been chosen before which can be identified from the customer array.

As the array is big and populated on runtime so I can't define it like

```
where cid not in (Customer[1,2,3,4...])
```

Help me learn a new thing, please.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://www.philliphaydon.com/2016/05/07/postgresql-and-its-array-datatype/

Comment: Why not simply: `select array_agg(distinct cid) from ...`? Why the `IF` and the apparent inefficient row-by-row processing?

Comment: I need to process it row by row. @a_horse_with_no_name . Here I am simulating calls data, so you don't get all the calls at a time, your data is populated row by row.

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?  It looks like of like pl/pgsql, but not quite.  What are the types of the variables?